# Magento 2.4.2: How to get order sub total in my custom module?

Tags: checkout, module, cart, magento2.4

With the code below, I am trying to get the order sub total. Please note I am querying the table that I created in the Magento Database. `$subtotal = $request->getOrderSubtotal();` doesn't get the subtotal. system.log shows the code flow doesn't go beyond this line `$this->_logger->info("At line 168");` I am not sure how to retrieve the record from the SQL results.

```
    <?php

namespace Perfectmakeupmirrors\CustomShipping\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;
use Perfectmakeupmirrors\PmmFedex\Model\PmmFedexCarrier;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

/**
 * Custom shipping model
 */
class Customshipping extends AbstractCarrier implements CarrierInterface
{
    const CAD_RATE = 1.26;
    const FEDEX_METHODS = [
        'EUROPE_FIRST_INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY' => 'Europe First Priority',
        'FEDEX_1_DAY_FREIGHT' => '1 Day Freight',
        'FEDEX_2_DAY_FREIGHT' => '2 Day Freight',
        'FEDEX_2_DAY' => '2 Day',
        'FEDEX_2_DAY_AM' => '2 Day AM',
        'FEDEX_3_DAY_FREIGHT' => '3 Day Freight',
        'FEDEX_EXPRESS_SAVER' => 'Express Saver',
        'FEDEX_GROUND' => 'Ground',
        'FIRST_OVERNIGHT' => 'First Overnight',
        'GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY' => 'Home Delivery',
        'INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY' => 'International Economy',
        'INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY_FREIGHT' => 'Intl Economy Freight',
        'INTERNATIONAL_FIRST' => 'International First',
        'INTERNATIONAL_GROUND' => 'International Ground',
        'INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY' => 'International Priority',
        'INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY_FREIGHT' => 'Intl Priority Freight',
        'PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT' => 'Priority Overnight',
        'SMART_POST' => 'Smart Post',
        'STANDARD_OVERNIGHT' => 'Standard Overnight',
        'FEDEX_FREIGHT' => 'Freight',
        'FEDEX_NATIONAL_FREIGHT' => 'National Freight'
    ];
    const SHIPPING_STANDARD = 'STD';
    const SHIPPING_2ND_DAY = '2DY';
    const SHIPPING_OVERNIGHT = 'ON';
    protected $_shipping_mode_strings = array(
        self::SHIPPING_STANDARD => 'Standard Ground',
        self::SHIPPING_2ND_DAY => 'Second Day',
        self::SHIPPING_OVERNIGHT => 'Next Day Air',
    );

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'customshipping';

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isFixed = true;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
     */
    private $rateResultFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
     */
    private $rateMethodFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Perfectmakeupmirrors\CustomShipping\Helper\Data
     */
    private $helper;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $_logger;

    private $carrierFedex;

    protected $resource;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        \Perfectmakeupmirrors\CustomShipping\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Perfectmakeupmirrors\PmmFedex\Model\PmmFedexCarrier $carrierFedex,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);

        $this->rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        $this->carrierFedex = $carrierFedex;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }

    /**
     * Custom Shipping Rates Collector
     *
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result|bool
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }
        
        $this->_logger->info("Start of Custom Shipping collectRates");
        if ($request->getDestCountryId() == "CA") {
            $this->_logger->info("Country ID: " . $request->getDestCountryId());
            $fedex_results = $this->carrierFedex->collectRates($request);
            // 1. Get the array of method objects from $fedex_results object
            // 2. Loop through the array of method objects to set carrier.
            // 3. Set carrier to custom shipping. 
            // 4. Add brokerage to the shipping cost based on the table canada_brokerage_fees.

            // \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $methods
            $methods = $fedex_results->getAllRates();
            $this->_logger->info("At line 136");
            foreach ($methods as $method) {
                $this->_logger->info("At line 138");
                $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
                // Set new price with brokerage added to the shipping cost.
                // Get subtotal from the $request object.
                // Recalculate subtotal in CAD
                // Create table canada_brokerage_fee in Magento DB
                // Compute brokerage.
                $subtotal = $request->getOrderSubtotal();
                $this->_logger->info("Sub total in USD: " . $subtotal);

                // Convert $subtotal from USD to CAD
                // 1 USD = 1.26 CAD
                $subtotal_cad = ($subtotal * 1.26);
                $this->_logger->info("Sub total in CAD: " . $subtotal_cad);

                // Create DB connection
                // http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-run-custom-sql-query/
                $connection    = $this->resource->getConnection();
                $tableName     = $this->resource->getTableName('canada_brokerage_fees');
                $this->_logger->info("At line 157");

                // Fetch relevant fee from the table canada_brokerage_fees 
                // based on the merchandise total.
                $sql = "SELECT brokerage_cost_cad FROM " . $tableName .  
                       " WHERE max_merchandise_cost <=" . $subtotal_cad . " ORDER BY brokerage_cost_cad DESC LIMIT 1";

                $this->_logger->info("At line 164");

                $result = $connection->query($sql);   

                $this->_logger->info("At line 168");
                
                $brokerage_cost_cad = $result['brokerage_cost_cad'];
                
                $this->_logger->info("At line 171");
                
                $this->_logger->info("brokerage in CAD: " . $brokerage_cost_cad);
                $method->setPrice($method->getPrice + $brokerage_cost_cad);
                $this->_logger->info("At line 175");
            }

            return $fedex_results;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->rateResultFactory->create();

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
        $method = $this->rateMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod($this->_code);
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        $this->_logger->info(__FILE__ . ': At Start');

        // Get all the items.
        // NOTE: This getAllItems here is related to Quote and not the order.
        if ((!($items = $request->getAllItems())) or (count($items) == 0)) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        // $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        // $attributeSet = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface');
        // $attributeSetRepository = $attributeSet->get(9);
        // $attribute_set_name = $attributeSetRepository->getAttributeSetName();
        // $this->_logger->info(__FILE__ . ": Attribute Set Name = $attribute_set_name");

        //Standard code commented. Custom code added.
        //$shippingCost = (float)$this->getConfigData('shipping_cost');
        $shippingCost = (float)$this->helper->compute_standard_shipping_cost($items);

        $method->setPrice($shippingCost);
        $method->setCost($shippingCost);

        $result->append($method);

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        $custom_shipping_methods = [$this->_code => $this->getConfigData('name')];
        $allowed_methods = array_merge($custom_shipping_methods, $this->FEDEX_METHODS);
        return $allowed_methods;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is line no 168?

Comment: Edited the post to show the line 168. I think `$brokerage_cost_cad = $result['brokerage_cost_cad'];` is causing some issue. syste,m.log doesn't indicate any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way to build sql:

```
$sql = $connection->select()->from($tableName)->where('max_merchandise_cost <= ?', $subtotal_cad)
->order('brokerage_cost_cad DESC')->limit(1);
// error_log($sql->__toString());
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

If your subtotal returns nothing, then you can try to get that from quote. Here is the code:

```
$quote = null;
    $items = $request->getAllItems();
    foreach($items as $item) {
        /** @var Quote $quote */
        $quote = $item->getQuote();
        break;
    }

    if (!$quote) {
        return false;
    }

    $quote->getSubtotal();
```

Comment: The SQL part is working, thanks. As for the subtotal code, is there a need on my part to create Quote $quote object through dependency injection? OR just use your code to get the subtotal?

Comment: Your code on subtotal also works fine. Nothing needed to do.